# How to get Full family Ids from single table from Parent child relation

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have a MySQL table (family) which is as follows

```
id parent_id 
4   null
5   4 
6   null 
7   null
36  5 
37  6
```

Here when I pass

```
id as 4 it should return 4 -5 - 36 
id as 5 it should return 4 -5 - 36 
id as 6 it should return 6 - 37 
id as 7 it should return 7
id as 36 it should return 4 -5 - 36 
id as 37 it should return 37 - 6 

SELECT t1.id AS lev1, t2.id as lev2, t3.id as lev3, t4.id as lev4
FROM family AS t1
LEFT JOIN family AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN family AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN family AS t4 ON t4.parent_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id =5;
```

But this code is failing in some cases. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: change nulls to 0

Comment: WHERE t1.id =57; 57?

Comment: @Dharmang its my mistake.. consider t1.id as 5 for now..

Answer (score 0):

Based on what's provided, i can see that 36 and 37 would not return the values you expect.

t1.id = 36

t2.parent_id should then = 36, but none of them do.

Also, 'failing' is pretty ambiguous is there an error or are you getting a different result than you expect? If the latter, it could be you're expecting the wrong result.

Comment: I am not getting values for id: 5, id:36 and 37

Comment: t1.id = 5 would give you the values
t1.id = 5
t2.id = 36
t3.id, t4.id = null

There is no field (from the provided) where parent_id = 36

Comment: but for id = 5 it should return 4 -5 -36 , but my query returning only 5 - 36... can you help me to improve query ?